# Run CSS and JS files through Azure CDN

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, cdn

I have put my cdn up and it works as it should but my js and css files do not run through my azure cdn.

I've built code like this here at bundleconfig.cs

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
var CDNname = "https://www.xxxx.com/CDN/";

//Style here
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/skins", CDNname).Include(
     "~/Content/skins/default.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/Scripts", CDNname)
     .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css")
     .Include("~/Scripts/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css")
     .Include("~/Scripts/owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css"));
```

Comment: try `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/skins", string.Format(CDNname, "bundles/skins")).Include(`

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari its not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the complete CDN path which can access the file hosted by CDN to the construction method of StyleBundle.

For example, if the CDN path of default.css is "https://www.xxxx.com/CDN/content/skins/default.css" (please make sure we can access the css file according this URL), you could use following code to add bundle.

```
var cdnPathOfDefaultCss = "https://www.xxxx.com/CDN/content/skins/default.css";
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/skins", cdnPathOfDefaultCss).Include(
         "~/Content/skins/default.css"));
```